# What is Windows's default searching order for executable suffixes?

Tags: windows

Assume I have a lot of files like these in a directory:

```
foo.exe foo.com foo.vbs foo.js foo.msi foo.bat foo.cmd
```

Now I run `foo` in Command Prompt in this directory. Which one will be executed? What is the searching order of the extensions of these executable files?

Comment: `which foo` will give you the answer.

Comment: @DavidPostill `'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` Is that a Linux command? I can find its manual with `man 1 which`...

Comment: Ah. try `where foo`